# user not in sudo group but can perform sudo operations

Tags: sudo, visudo

Is this normal behaviour when I put a user student in sudoers file using visudo command like this :

```
visudo 

student   ALL = NOPASSWD:   ALL
```

And he is not in sudo group but can still perform sudo operations ?

So if a user is decribed in sudoers file he doesn't need to be in sudo group ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normal. By default you have in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So all users from the `sudo` group are allowed to do any operation. Adding a user to this group gives permissions because of this line.

You can add a separate user there as well.